# Included file does not have a valid YAML syntax

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

I am including a remote .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
variables:
   ENTITY_NAME: $CI_PROJECT_TITLE

include:
   remote: 'https://gitlab.com/paulblart/paul_test/-/main/.gitlab-ci.yml'
```

but checking for it YAML syntax in CI Lint GUI its saying

> Included file 'https://gitlab.com/paulblart/paul_test/-/main/.gitlab-ci.yml' does not have valid YAML syntax!

But upon checking the syntax of .gitlab-ci.yml of the remote file its valid. I am not sure whats going on.

Comment: AFAIU the URL `https://gitlab.com/paulblart/paul_test/-/main/.gitlab-ci.yml` doesn't point to the YAML file, it points to a web page. It must be `https://gitlab.com/paulblart/paul_test/-/raw/main/.gitlab-ci.yml`, I think.

Comment: The syntax was fixed! I was following the documentation, but it never menitoned to have the raw instance of the file. Thank you @phd

Comment: Obsolete documentation? URL format was changed later?

Answer (score 5):

**I have workaround for this issue**

```
include:
   - project: "my-project-with-yml/project-name"
     ref: master
     file: "/yml/.gitlab-ci.yaml"
     rules: ## Optional, to show the support to **rules**
     - if: $variable == "condition "
```

I was also facing the issue with YAML Error, even though the lint was green.

Comment: Thank you! You've saved me hours of digging. This was my issue as well! My CICD template had a long name and it looks like GitLab doesn't take that well as mentioned by ashish-bustler. Just wanted to add a [link to the documentation page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#include-an-array-of-configuration-files) for an example of using the project sub-clause under include clause

Answer (score 2):

I saw a different version of problem in my case, I was trying to set CI/CD configuration file pointing to a different project with relatively longer name of a valid yaml file. I checked the linting, file was yaml but error thrown while attempting to run the pipeline was:
Included file `.gitlab-ci-a-very-long-gilabci-file.yml@group/subgroup/pipeline-project` does not have YAML extension!

Shortening the name solved it, Gitlab can improve the error messages.
Just adding as I didn't find it on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error come up when I was trying to access a gitlab group which wasn't public, so I didn't have rights to look at the file.

Very uninformative error in that case.

Answer (score 0):

As @phd mentioned correct, you should open raw version of the file and use it for inclusion. Because you a trying to include gitlab UI page that shows pretty version of the file.

[image]